# Pass JSON value from JavaScript to JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I am working on a code to get a JSON value from javascript to my JSP. The JSON value is a boolean, so I could use if/else in my JSP script. I have two javascript files and a JSP.

Widget.js

```
initialize: function(conf){
  _Widget.prototype.initialize.call(this);
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onPChange', 'applyInfo');
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
  this.listenTo(this.model, 'error', this.handleError);
  conf.getBus().on('/p'. this.onPChange);
  return this;
},
serializeData: function(model){
  return _.extend({}, this.resStr, model.attributes);
}
render: function(model, resp, options){
  var data;
  f = JSON.stringify(data.sFund);
  console.log("Result value: " + f);
}
```

index.js

```
$('#wgtWidget').objFactory(this.classes, this.wgts, this.mdls, conf);
this.mdls['wgtWidget'].render();
```

Portlet.jsp

```
<div data-wgt='Widget' data-model='Model' id='wgtWidget' class='model'></div>
<script>
  var f;
  console.log("Returned JSON value: " + f);
  if(f==true)
     console.log("Success");
</script>
```

I grunt the javascript files to make a minified main.js file. When I tried commit the above code, I get

```
conf.getBus is not defined
```

error, while I get the log as:

```
Result value: true
Returned JSON value: undefined
```

If I change the JSP as:

Portlet.jsp

```
<!-- <div data-wgt='Widget' data-model='Model' id='wgtWidget' class='model'></div> -->
<script>
  var f;
  console.log("Returned JSON value: " + f);
  if(f==true)
     console.log("Success");
</script>
```

Now I get the:

```
this.mdls.wgtWidget is not defined
```

and no other log.

I tried removing the line

```
this.mdls['wgtWidget'].render();
```

from the index.js code. This makes the page load without errors, but no other log.

Can you please help me get this over with? I am struggling to find an answer from 3 days.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With considerable amount of time and work, I understood that the value is not being passed as it is. I just removed a.getBus(); from Widget.js and the stuff works like wonder.